# Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PollModel'. Property 'pollId' is missing in type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

Good day.

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'PollModel'. Property 'pollId' is missing in type 'any[]'.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" (click)="showAddModal('add',[])"> Create a poll</i></button>
```

Component:

```
showAddModal(action: string, poll: PollModel) {
            //show add modal method
            }
```

Model:

```
export class PollModel {
  pollId: string;
  pollName: string;
  pollDesc: string;
  pollOwnerId: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  createdDate: Date;
  modifiedDate: Date;
  pollType: string;
}
```

I am trying to pass an empty array as a model. However I got the error above. I am new to angular. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the `PollModel` interface/class to the question ?

Comment: What is your purpose? You just want to initiate an empty array?

Comment: Added pollmodel @AnuradhaGunasekara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `showAddModal` function expects **two parameters** first is a **string**,  second is a **object of type `PollModel`**.

But in the question you are passing an **array as the second argument**. That's why you are getting this error.

You should either change the method syntax or the parameter type as following.

```
<button type="button" (click)="showAddModal('add',[])"> Create a poll</i></button>

showAddModal(action: string, poll: PollModel[]) {
            //show add modal method
}
```

or

create a object with `PollModel` properties and pass it as an argument.

```
<button type="button" (click)="showAddModal('add',{'id': 2})"> Create a poll</i></button>

showAddModal(action: string, poll: PollModel) {
            //show add modal method
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your component script should be

```
showAddModal(action: string, poll: PollModel[]) {
        //show add modal method
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1** This will work if you want Array inside the function:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" (click)="showAddModal('add')"> Create a poll</i></button>
```

Component:

```
showAddModal(action: string, poll: PollModel[] = []) {
      //show add modal method
}
```

**Way 2** This will work if you want object inside the function:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" (click)="showAddModal('add')"> Create a poll</i></button>
```

Component:

```
showAddModal(action: string, poll: any = {}) {
      //show add modal method
}
```